# Explanation of Divisibility in Lucas' Theorem Proof

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I was reading about the Lucas theorem, and encountered a resource [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30002.4-5.shtml).

I understand the argument it is making, but slightly thrown off by this line here: "Note this argument only works when p is prime."

**My question is: why is it that this argument only works when p is prime?**

$k{p^r\choose k}= p^r{p^r-1 \choose k-1}$ where $0 < k < p^r$ implies that ${p^r\choose k}$ is divisible by $p$.

For example, it seems to me to work with $p=4$ and $r=4$ for example.
Clearly the right side is still divisible by $4^4$, whereas k cannot possibly be divisible by $4^4$ since it is less than $p^r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But $k$ could be equal to $2^7 =\frac{4^4}2$, for example. In this case, you can only conclude that ${p^r \choose k}$ is divisible by $2$, not by $4$. That can't happen when $p$ is prime.

As Brian Moehring pointed out in the comments, it's not only true that the conclusion method fails, but that ${4^4 \choose 2^7}$ is actually not divisble by $4$.

To see that, we start with the equality given in the problem, for our special counter example

$$2^7{4^4 \choose 2^7} = 4^4{4^4-1 \choose 2^7-1}$$

and divide by $2^7$
$${4^4 \choose 2^7} = 2{4^4-1 \choose 2^7-1}.$$

We now have

$${4^4-1 \choose 2^7-1} = \frac{(4^4-1)\times(4^4-2)\times\ldots\times(2^7+1)}{1\times 2 \times \ldots \times (2^7-1)}$$

Note that in that quotient the $i$-th factor in the enumerator and the $i$-th factor in the denominator add up to exactly $4^4$. That means the powers of $2$ contained in the $i$-th factor in the enumerator are **exactly the same** as in the $i$-the factor in the denominator. 
That means after cancelling all those powers of $2$, you are left with a product of of odd numbers in both enumerator and denominator, which means ${4^4-1 \choose 2^7-1}$ is odd, proving what Brian said.

Comment: It's useful to also note that this isn't a flaw of the proof method, but rather we can show $$\binom{4^4}{2^7} \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$$ so in fact the statement that $p$ divides $\binom{p^r}{k}$ would be false for this composite choice of $p$

Comment: Thank you for that example.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure this was actually the case.

Comment: @Ingix The easiest (i.e. least computation) way to see this is by the theorem stating $p^r$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $\binom{n}{k}$ if and only if there are $r$ "carries" when adding $k + (n-k)$ in base $p.$  In this case, $2^7 + (4^4-2^7) = 2^7 + 2^7$ only has one carry from the $2^7$ place to the $2^8$ place.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Once you said it was true, I remembered the trick I used above to show such things, and it seems to work.